# How to save concatenated output of CSV files

Tags: python

How to save the concatenated output of CSV files. I have executed this command and it concatenates all my files, but I don't know how to save the concatenated files again in my drive `Path as /content/drive/My Drive/infy`

This is the command

```
stockfiles = sorted(glob('/content/drive/My Drive/infy/*.csv'))
stockfiles

pandas.concat((pandas.read_csv(onefile).assign(filename= onefile)
  for onefile in stockfiles), ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to save the concatenated DataFrames to a csv? If so, here is how https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a function to directly write the data-frame to a path as csv file.

```py
df.to_csv(<path_to_file> + <file_name.csv>)
```

[link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the DataFrame that pandas.concat returns to a CSV. First, store the dataframe in a variable.

`df = pandas.concat((pandas.read_csv(onefile).assign(filename= onefile) for onefile in stockfiles), ignore_index = True)`

Then set your file name.

`file_name = /content/drive/My Drive/infy/FILENAME`

Lastly, save to a CSV

`df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')`